# How to add data to CollectionView from BindingContext from another page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this below click button on the MainPage, it works fine and I can see the data displayed if I pass(Bind) data to a Label in the second page(CourseDetailViewPage);

but now I want to display data in a collectionview located in the second page(CourseDetailPage).

```
//Click button in MainPage
        public async void OnOkGetCourseButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputtedCourseNumber = ctrlEntryTextBox.Text;

            if(inputtedCourseNumber == string.Empty)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Note", "\nPlease enter your Course number", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {

                    CourseService CourseService = new CourseService();
                    var data = await CourseService.getCourses();

                    var userCourse = data.Where(x => x.Id.ToString() == inputtedCourseNumber).FirstOrDefault();

                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

                    if (userCourse == null)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Note", "\nCourse number does not exist. Verify your Course number", "OK");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Note", "\nOurahh - Course number found !!!", "OK");

                        await DisplayAlert("Note", "\n" + userCourse.Id + "\n" + userCourse.CourseDetail + "\n" + userCourse.IsCourseComplete + "\n" + userCourse.CourseDate, "OK");



                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new CourseDetailPage
                        {
                            BindingContext = userCourse as Course
                        });


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error Network", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
```

======

```
// CourseDetailPage (Second page)
        
        <CollectionView x:Name="myCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding userCourse}" 
                            HeightRequest="200">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CourseDetail}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding IsCourseComplete}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: pass the selected Course to the 2nd page and add it to the CollectionView's ItemsSource

Comment: I already did it but it's still not working. Please see the code at the bottom of my first post.  **userCourse** in the MainPage is the variable that holds the data that I want to pass to the second page, on the collection view.

Comment: `{Binding userCourse}` - your CollectionView is looking for a property name `userCourse` that will contain a **list** of data to display.  You are (apparently) assigning a single course as the binding context for the page, so that will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CourseDetailPage
{
    BindingContext = userCourse as Course
});
```

To

```
ObservableCollection<Course> courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>();
courses.Add(userCourse);
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CourseDetailPage
{
    BindingContext = courses
});
```

REASON: You need to pass a *collection* to ItemsSource. In this simple situation, it wouldn't have to be an "Observable"Collection, but in more dynamic uses, where code adds/removes elements while a list of items is displayed, that is likely to be what you'll want. So I used it here, as a good habit.

Change

```
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding userCourse}" 
                HeightRequest="200">
```

To

```
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" 
                HeightRequest="200">
```

REASON: In the first code change, we set BindingContext of the new CourseDetailPage to the collection that we want to use as ItemsSource. "{Binding .}" is a way to refer to the BindingContext itself. In this case, the BindingContext *is* the list to use as ItemsSource.

---

NOTE: While the above should work, it is limiting. It doesn't offer any way to pass other values, to other parts of `CourseDetailPage`. If you find that you want to pass `userCourse` AND some other information, then it is slightly more involved.

Define a class that has a *public property* `Courses`, and pass an instance of that class as BindingContext. THEN ItemsSource will be `{Binding Courses}`:

```
public class Details
{
    public property ObservableCollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public property int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

...
ObservableCollection<Course> courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>();
courses.Add(userCourse);
var details = new Details { Courses = courses, Prop2 = 123 };

await Navigation.PushAsync(new CourseDetailPage
{
    BindingContext = details 
});

...
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" 
                HeightRequest="200">

... some other view that uses `..="{Binding Prop2}"` ...
```

This is a "one-way" display of data. If user needs to *interact* with the data, then look into [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.